# Saving a Canvas as an image in UWP

Tags: javascript, uwp, winjs

I found [this documentation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf8c17dc-68d4-4777-951f-bb7f0665bd06/saving-a-canvas-as-an-image-in-windows-8?forum=winappswithhtml5) for exporting and saving a Canvas as a png. It gives the following code:

```
var Imaging = Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
picker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.picturesLibrary;
picker.fileTypeChoices.insert("PNG file", [".png"]);
var imgData, fileStream = null;
picker.pickSaveFileAsync().then(function (file) {            
    if (file) {
        return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);                
    } else {
        return WinJS.Promise.wrapError("No file selected");
    }
}).then(function (stream) {
    fileStream = stream;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");            
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    return Imaging.BitmapEncoder.createAsync(Imaging.BitmapEncoder.pngEncoderId, stream);
}).then(function (encoder) {
    //Set the pixel data--assume "encoding" object has options from elsewhere
    encoder.setPixelData(encoding.pixelFormat, encoding.alphaMode,
        encoding.width, encoding.height, encoding.dpiX, encoding.dpiY,
        new Uint8Array(imgData.data));
    //Go do the encoding
    return encoder.flushAsync();
}).done(function () {
    //Make sure to do this at the end
    fileStream.close();  
}, function () {
    //Empty error handler (do nothing if the user canceled the picker
});
```

In the 'encoder.setPixelData' area, they use an object called 'encoding' to set all the values, but have no explanation of how this object is created in any of the prior steps.

How can I create this 'encoding' object to complete the example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different way to save the canvas, still didn't solve my initial problem

I can turn the canvas into a blob stream and save that to a png file

```
function saveCanvasAsImage(canvasElement) {
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
    picker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.picturesLibrary;
    picker.fileTypeChoices.insert("PNG file", [".png"]);

    var input, output = null;
    var blob = canvasElement.msToBlob();

    return picker.pickSaveFileAsync()
        .then(function (file) {
            if (file) {
                return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
            } else {
                return WinJS.Promise.wrapError("No file selected");
            }
        })
        .then(function (op) {
            output = op;
            input = blob.msDetachStream();

            return Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStream.copyAsync(input, output);
        })
        .then(function() {
            return output.flushAsync();
        })
        .done(function() {
            input.close();
            output.close();
        }, function(e) {
            // handle error here
        });
}
```

Unfortunately it's saving with a transparent background, but maybe there's a way I can make my canvas have a white background.

[edit] ----

So I found a way to answer my original question more directly:

```
function saveCanvasAsImage(canvasElement) {
    var Imaging = Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
    var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
    picker.suggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.picturesLibrary;
    // picker.fileTypeChoices.insert("JPEG file", [".jpg"]);
    picker.fileTypeChoices.insert("PNG file", [".png"]);
    var fileStream, decoder, encoding, pixels = null;


    var encoderIds = {
        '.png': Imaging.BitmapEncoder.pngEncoderId,
        '.jpg': Imaging.BitmapEncoder.jpegEncoderId
    }

    var encoderId = encoderIds['.jpg'];

    var blob = canvasElement.msToBlob();

    return Imaging.BitmapDecoder.createAsync(Imaging.BitmapDecoder.pngDecoderId,
            blob.msDetachStream())
        .then(function (dc) {
            decoder = dc;

            return picker.pickSaveFileAsync();
        }).then(function (file) {
            if (file) {
                encoderId = encoderIds[file.fileType];
                return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
            } else {
                return WinJS.Promise.wrapError("No file selected");
            }
        }).then(function(stream) {
            fileStream = stream;

            var transform = new Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTransform();

            return decoder.getPixelDataAsync(
                decoder.bitmapPixelFormat,
                decoder.bitmapAlphaMode,
                transform,
                Windows.Graphics.Imaging.ExifOrientationMode.respectExifOrientation,
                Windows.Graphics.Imaging.ColorManagementMode.colorManageToSRgb
            );

        }).then(function (pixelProvider) {

            pixels = pixelProvider.detachPixelData();

            return Imaging.BitmapEncoder.createAsync(encoderId, fileStream);
        }).then(function (encoder) {
            encoding = decoder;
            //Set the pixel data--assume "encoding" object has options from elsewhere
            encoder.setPixelData(encoding.bitmapPixelFormat, encoding.bitmapAlphaMode,
                encoding.pixelWidth, encoding.pixelHeight, encoding.dpiX, encoding.dpiY,
                pixels);
            //Go do the encoding
            return encoder.flushAsync();
        }).done(function () {
            //Make sure to do this at the end
            fileStream.close();
        }, function () {
            //Empty error handler (do nothing if the user canceled the picker
        });
}
```

I've commented out the ability to save as JPG because that's a new problem, but this works for pngs

Answer (score 0):

Place your canvas within a Grid with background white and then render it using RenderTargetBitmap. It worked fine for me.

```
            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
            await rtb.RenderAsync("Your Grid containing canvas goes here");    
            var pixelBuffer = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
            var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
            var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();
            FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
            savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("png", new List<string>() { ".png" });
            savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "PNG File";
            StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
```

Comment: Where is this function RenderTargetBitmap? I looked in `Windows.Graphics.Imaging` but couldn't find it

Comment: Using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging

Comment: It's not in there for me in my html/javascript app. I can access Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging -- it's defined, but it doesn't have anything insite it, and Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap is undefined. I'm not using XAML though, so that's probably why.